# Kubernetes: How do I get the status and restarts of a container using python?

Tags: python, kubernetes, restart, status

I would like to get the container status and restarts of a pod, using [python kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python). I am currently using [list_namespaced_pod](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#list_namespaced_pod) to get the pods and the [container status](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1ContainerStatus.md), which I interpret as the status of the pod. This works, but is far from an ideal solution. I am looking for something that gives me similar information to `kubectl -n $NAMESPACE get pods`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the following for example, to get all the pods and their status:

```
api_response = api_instance.list_namespaced_pod(namespace, pretty=pretty, timeout_seconds=timeout_seconds, watch=watch)

for i in api_response.items:
    print(i.metadata.name + " " + i.status.phase)
```

Comment: When my pod status is PullImageError, I get with the code above: (i.status.phase) 'Pending', PullImageError can be found in 'i.container_statuses'

Comment: Is you K8s cluster having troubling pulling the container image?

Comment: It was, and I needed to get the exact error from within python. Shame their documentation is so hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @rico's answer,

```python
for pod in api_response.items:
    status = pod.status.phase    
    container_status = pod.status.container_statuses[0]
    if container_status.started is False or container_status.ready is False:
        waiting_state = container_status.state.waiting
        if waiting_state.message is not None and 'Error' in waiting_state.message:
            status = waiting_state.reason
    print(pod.metadata.name + " " + status)
```

You can also loop on the api call 'api_instance.list_namespaced_pod' to see the statuses  changing online like in kubectl -n $NAMESPACE get pods -w